# DXA 2.0 Java Too many open files error

Tags: dxa-java, dxa-2.0, linux, tomcat

We are using DXA 2.0 Java inside RedHat Linux server. The DXA Application is deployed using Tomcat 8.5.

While accessing website after some time we are getting 500 error too many open files although we have increase open file limit in Tomcat service file. We know this not related to DXA but any advice will be helpful. Below is Tomcat service file

```
# Systemd unit file for tomcat
[Unit] 
Description=Apache Tomcat Web Application Container LB1 
After=syslog.target network.target 

[Service] 
Type=forking
LimitNOFILE=20786

Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_161/jre 
Environment=CATALINA_PID=/u01/tomcat-lb1/temp/tomcat.pid 
Environment=CATALINA_HOME=/u01/tomcat 
Environment=CATALINA_BASE=/u01/tomcat-lb1 
Environment='CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC' 
Environment='JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Dconnector.ip=10.0.0.0 -Dconnector.port=901' 

ExecStart=/u01/tomcat/bin/startup.sh 
ExecStop=/bin/kill -15 $MAINPID


User=ipMonitor
Group=kcAlerts
UMask=0007 
RestartSec=10 
Restart=always

[Install] 
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Can you **edit** your question and provide some more details on it, like what setting exactly did you increase etc. I see for instance the info here https://serverfault.com/questions/729996/java-io-ioexception-too-many-open-files-on-tomcat-server that might be relevant.

Comment: Again I suggest you **edit** your question once more and provide more details, you mention the "Tomcat service file", but I suggest you specify which file that is exactly? In the question I found on StackExchange, it mentions a `/etc/security/limits.conf` file, it doesn't look like you edited that. You can check limits of a running process with `cat /proc/xxxx/limits` where `xxxx` is the pid of the Tomcat process, maybe you can specify what that limit currently is, hopefully then you can get some more relevant answers, or post this question on serverfault.com where it is more relevant.

Comment: @BartKoopman thanks for your valuable suggestion i have posted this issue on serverfault.com   "https://serverfault.com/questions/915619/fork-resource-temporarily-unavailable-due-to-tomcat-java-process" hope will get a reply soon.